# страница сайта выдает ошибку 500

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code

Пишу сайт, который запускается на `apache`. Отладку сайта произвожу через встроенный в VS Code `PHP built-in server`. Все страницы сайта отображаются корректно как через встроенный в PHP сервер так и через Apache.

**Все - кроме одной**.

Использую маршрутизацию. Когда в поисковой строке указано `localhost/view/calendar` - то на PHP сервере все работает исправно, а на `apache` при попытке загрузить страницу получаю ошибку 500.

Проблема в том что когда я занимаюсь отладкой кода включается встроенный PHP сервер, на котором все работает и из-за этого я не могу посмотреть что в коде ломается при загрузке через `apache`.

*Вопрос:* **Как установить в качестве сервера отладки - `apache`, чтобы можно было увидеть поломку???**

P.S. Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)